# Google Cloud Client for Cloud Storage with App Engine Standard (Python 2.7)

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-app-engine-python

I'm trying to use Google Cloud Storage with App Engine Standard (Python 2.7).

I've been trying to follow the simple 4-step installation instructions here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/migrate-to-python3/migrate-to-storage-apis#install

After following the instructions, when trying to run, I get a message "ImportError: No module named pkg_resources" caused by the `import pkg_resources` at the top of appengine_config.py.  I don't understand how this is supposed to work, since the vendor.add call comes later in the file, so the pkg_resources installed in lib is not yet available.  If pkg_resources is supposed to be present elsewhere, where? Somewhere in the app engine installation? How would it get there?

I do already have other third-party libraries installed and working in lib, so that part of the configuration is probably ok.  That being said, these instructions do install A LOT of libraries into this app-specific lib folder, which I'd love to avoid if possible.

Anyway, I can work around this pkg_resources problem by importing pkg_resources after the vendor.add call (but it leaves me concerned that the instructions aren't working).

With the workaround, I then get "ImportError: No module named moves" from file C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\google\cloud_helpers.py, line 29, in  'from six.moves import http_client`.  There is no "six" folder in "lib", only "six.py".

I feel as if I may be missing something, since the original instructions are so simple, yet not working for me.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Python 2 has not been supported for years. Port your application to Python 3 before trying to deploy it to App Engine. Do not use Python 2 transition libraries.

Comment: @JohnHanley, unfortunately, porting an App Engine app to Python 3 involves A LOT of other changes, since Google used the change from Python 2 to Python 3 to also change the basic architecture and eliminate a number of previously built-in services.  The recent article linked at the top of this page is designed specifically for this situation, and purports to provide instructions for using a Python 2 App Engine deployment with Google Cloud Storage.

Comment: `pkg_resources` is a part of Python's `setuptools` package. That package dropped support for Python 2 at version 45. Are you perhaps using a recent version of setuptools and not version `36.6.0`?

Comment: Getting a Python 2 app to run will also take a lot of changes. You might want to consider Compute Engine or Cloud Run where you can run Python 2 applications without a lot of changes.

Comment: @BrandonYarbrough, good suggestion, and while we had specified 36.6.0 in app.yaml, the other instructions ended up installing a somewhat later version.  However, that didn't fix anything.  In the end, we're going to have to stick with our first workaround described above, and there's a documented workaround for the second problem at https://github.com/googleapis/python-ndb/issues/249#issuecomment-560957294

Comment: Could you post the workaround that worked for you as an answer so that other community members could get help in a similar scenario.

Comment: @VaidehiJamankar, OK.  The first workaround is described in my question above.  The second necessary workaround, as linked in my comment, is to import the six module, then six.moves.reload_module(six).  I don't know why this works, but it is a a recommended Github solution to the issue.